# Why am I getting Oracle "invalid number" on my query when I am doing no type conversion?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a website that creates this SQL for one of the backend database queries (simplifying it for the question)

```
 Select * 
   from People 
   where Status = 'Active'
     and GroupId = 103403 
     and  (TeamName in ('TEAM1', 'TEAM2')) 
     and DELETED is NULL
```

and this works fine.  I now need to add a few new team names, something like this

```
Select * 
  from People 
   where Status = 'Active'
   and GroupId = 103403 
   and  (TeamName in ('TEAM1', 'TEAM2','TEAM3', 'TEAM4')) 
   and DELETED is NULL
```

and i get this error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

what is weird is that it doesn't seem to be anything wrong with "TEAM3" or "TEAM4" as if i do this

```
Select * 
  from People 
   where Status = 'Active'
   and GroupId = 103403 
   and  (TeamName in ('TEAM3', 'TEAM4')) 
   and DELETED is NULL
```

it also works fine.  So only when i have a certain number of teams in the "IN" condition is when it breaks.

Any suggestions for what the issue could be.  When I google that Oracle error all I see if people that have some conversion logic in their SQL as the root cause due to data type mismatching but I don't have any conversion logic here.

Comment: When you enclose a string literal with double quotes( `Status = "Active" in your question`) Oracle treats it as an identifier and a case-sensitive one at that. And if your query is not a part of pl/sql block where such an identifier is declared, then it should generate an error `ORA-00904: invalid identifier`. Besides that, check if your `GroupId` is of `varchar2` datatype.

Comment: Please show the `create table` statement for the `people` table.

Comment: @Nicholas - that was a typo . . fixed in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that *GroupId* isn't a numeric column. And depending on your other conditions, the condition `GroupId = 103403` is evaluated before or after the other conditions. If it's evaluated for a row that contains an invalid number in the `GroupId` column, then your query fails.

If my assumption is correct, the change the condition to:

```
GroupId = '10340'
```

BTW: Please post the real SQL code, the code you have run in your own tests. Your current code contains double quotes, which hardly works.